# Does ruby need ternary operator at all?

Tags: ruby, conditional-operator

I made a small test today:

```
> false && 1 || 2
> 2
> true && 1 || 2
> 1
```

So if we could already do with binary operators, why did we need a ternary ?

```
> false ? 1 : 2
> 2
> true ? 1 : 2
> 1
```

As it is not simply an alias and complicates parsing.

Comment: You are correct in that one doesn't 'need' the ternary in Ruby.. but look at both the examples you provided above and tell me which one reads better..

Comment: I agree with Ilan. The ternary operator example reads much better.

Comment: @ilanberci I don't think anyone's subjective opinion should play a role on the matter. I was wondering if there was a corner case where binary operators aren't an adequate replacement

Comment: @nurettin many of Ruby's language constructs are a matter of 'subjective opinion'.  When Matz designed the language, it was his intent to make the langage fun to program in.  What is 'fun'??  ... subjective...

Comment: @ilanberci that's mr. matz. All hail mr. matz.

Comment: @nurettin  I had to upvote your comment for that!  I stand corrected.. please forgive me

Comment: *Ternary* means 'has three parameters'. This is the *conditional* operator, which happens to be ternary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deal with the specific case in your question…

What if `1` was different value, one that evaluated as false?

And in general:

No. You can always replace a ternary operator with an `if/else` construct. That isn't as convenient though.

Comment: `what if 1 was different value, one that evaluated as false?` 

`false && false || 2` would equal `2` as expected.

Comment: @nurettin: how about `true && false || 2` vs. `true ? false : 2` ?

Comment: @RemusRusanu corner case found :-)

Answer (score 1):

No language *needs* a ternary operator.

The ternary operator is a well-known language construct. IMO people generally expect it in script-ish(-looking) languages, so there it is. I don't see a huge reason to *not* have it.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional operator is needed in languages like C, because `if`/`else` is a *statement*, it doesn't evaluate to a return value. But in Ruby, *everything* is an expression, *everything* has a return value, there are no statements.

Therefore, you can *always* replace the conditional operator with a conditional expression:

```
foo = bar ? baz : qux
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
foo = if bar then baz else qux end
```

In C, you cannot write this, you'd have to write

```
if bar then foo = baz else foo = aux end
```

leading to code duplication. That's why you need the conditional operator in C. In Ruby, it is unnecessary.

Actually, since Ruby is an object-oriented language, *all* conditionals are unnecessary. You can just use polymorphism instead.

Comment: (I'd argue that's it's a desire, not a need, in C-ish languages.)